# where the type class is called in form collection type

Tags: php, symfony

hi all my problem is the following : For example in a AType class i do:

```
$builder
    ->add('responses', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new BType()))
```

I want to know where the BType is called to help rendering of AType within a twig template

```
{{ entityA.responses }}
```

EDIT:

Look at the code i used in my controller, i create new B (entity class) objects and add the all in an arrayCollection, and finally pass that arrayCollection to a method setBs of A class. In all the turn i never use BType.

Code of my controller:

```
$b1 = new B();
$b2 = new B();

$array = new ArrayCollection();
$array->add($b1);
$array->add($b2);

$a = new A();
$a->setBs($array);

$form = $this->createForm(new AType(), $a)
```

I want to pass some options to the BType class, that's why i want to know where it's called. 
If there is another possibility to do it, that's welcome (i m newbe :) )